# Selecting count of multiple columns but only include the count if a columns value is more than 0

Tags: mysql

Not sure if I explained the issue correctly in the title, but basically I have this table which saves a players stage times:

```
CREATE TABLE `stagetimes` 
  ( 
     `steamid` VARCHAR(32) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT '', 
     `name`    VARCHAR(32) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL, 
     `mapname` VARCHAR(32) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT '', 
     `s1`      FLOAT DEFAULT '-1', 
     `s2`      FLOAT DEFAULT '-1', 
     `s3`      FLOAT DEFAULT '-1', 
     `s4`      FLOAT DEFAULT '-1', 
     `s5`      FLOAT DEFAULT '-1' 
  ) 
engine=innodb
ALTER TABLE `stagetimes`
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`steamid`,`mapname`);
```

This table actually goes up to s35 but to keep it simple, I left the rest out.

As soon as someone completes stage 1, a new row gets inserted with their steamid, their name, the map name and their stage 1 time with the rest of columns being -1 and being updated once they beat the additional stages, however, not every map has 5 stages, some may only have 4 or even less, so obviously if the columns value for a player is -1, the stage either doesn't exist or they haven't finished the stage therefore not updating the time from -1.

I want to select the total amount of stages that a specific player has completed as a count basically; I made up a query which works but it is extremely long and I was wondering if there was another way to achieve this:

```
SELECT Sum(stages) 
FROM   ((SELECT Count(`s1`) AS `stages` 
         FROM   `stagetimes` 
         WHERE  `steamid` = 'STEAM_1:0:00000000' 
                AND `s1` > 0) 
        UNION ALL 
        (SELECT Count(`s2`) AS `stages` 
         FROM   `stagetimes` 
         WHERE  `steamid` = 'STEAM_1:0:00000000' 
                AND `s2` > 0) 
        UNION ALL 
        (SELECT Count(`s3`) AS `stages` 
         FROM   `stagetimes` 
         WHERE  `steamid` = 'STEAM_1:0:00000000' 
                AND `s3` > 0) 
        UNION ALL 
        (SELECT Count(`s4`) AS `stages` 
         FROM   `stagetimes` 
         WHERE  `steamid` = 'STEAM_1:0:00000000' 
                AND `s4` > 0) 
        UNION ALL 
        (SELECT Count(`s5`) AS `stages` 
         FROM   `stagetimes` 
         WHERE  `steamid` = 'STEAM_1:0:00000000' 
                AND `s5` > 0)) t1
```

I don't really want to be doing this 35 times if it can be avoided.

Sample Data:

```
+-------------------+------------+---------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|      steamid      |    name    |    mapname    |   s1   |   s2   |   s3   |   s4   |   s5   |
+-------------------+------------+---------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|STEAM_1:0:20019070 |  fluffys   | surf_catrix   | 13.562 | 12.593 | 14.328 | 21.984 |   -1   |
|STEAM_1:0:20019070 |  fluffys   | surf_beginner |  2.753 |  9.185 | 14.406 | 23.359 | 11.343 |
+-------------------+------------+---------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

From this data, the query should return 9 as there are 9 stages that don't have the value of -1

Comment: How is the `stagetimes` table at the top related to `ck_wrcps` in the query?

Comment: my bad, fixed the table name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `SUM()` rather than `COUNT()` to put it into a single query. Conditional expressions return `1` when they're true, `0` when they're false, so you can simply add them.

```
SELECT SUM((s1 > 0) + (s2 > 0) + (s3 > 0) + (s4 > 0) + (s5 > 0)) AS total_stages
FROM stagetimes
WHERE steamid = 'STEAM_1:0:00000000'
```

It would probably be better to reorganize your schema. Instead of having each stage as a column in the table, have a separate row for each stage, with the stage number as a column. Then you would only have rows for the stages that actually exist.

Comment: This didn't work for me, I added some sample data to the original post, your query only returned `2` most likely because there are 2 records, but I'm trying to count all the stages that aren't -1. I also originally had the schema organized in that way, but there were far too many records for

Comment: Sorry, operator precedence problem. Need parentheses around each condition.